# What to do with water from dehumidifier?

Tags: water, waste

I have a room that is too humid during the summer, so I run a dehumidifier basically constantly.  If I don't, I start getting mold.  This means that I have to empty the basin at least once a day.  Right now, my routine is to just pour it down the toilet.

I wonder, is there something better I could be doing with it?  It seems like a decent amount of water that I'm currently wasting over a whole season.

Comment: Water the house plants with it. Wash dishes or yourself with it. Tip it into the washing machine. Wash the floor with it. Instead of tipping it into a drain, and wasting resources to send the same (or equivalent) water back to the tap (faucet in some places). Be creative, but don't drink it.

Answer (score 1):

If you consider that you are collecting atmospheric moisture, which may eventually fall as rain if not processed in this manner, or collect as dew on the grass, returning the water to the ground may be the best option you have.

If it's going into a sewage system, it is processed (although not needed) and eventually returns to the system, but pouring it on grass skips a lot of the middle sequences, for better efficiency, in my opinion.

If your dehumidifier has the feature of an external drain and it fits your environment, a hose to the outside will reduce the human labor portion.

Answer (score 1):

I do 2 things:

1)Put it in a bucket placed close to the toilet so that I can use that water instead of flushing (this bucket is also filled with excess iron water and the water I spend before taking a bath until it reaches a good hot temperature)

2)Water the plants I have at my balcony

Answer (score 0):

The chances may be slim, but I wouldn't do anything that involves further human contact with it. Legionella might not be common, but it is always a possibility.

Water the garden, flush the toilet, all valid uses - but don't wash in it or spray your plants.